# How to reformat Windows 10 and delete partitions

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, partitioning, formatting

I have a Dell Latitude laptop which I purchased many years ago with Windows 8 Pro.

I have upgraded to Windows 10 few years ago by a regular method that was given at the time and have reformatted it a couple of times since which automatically defaults to Windows 10.

I am now wanting to reformat it and although I understand the process of reformat/reset I can't find a way to delete the partitions I have set when reformatting which used to be the case in previous version of Windows during setup.

Is there a way to do this? I don't have any backup discs for the operating system so don't want to be in a position where I reformat and manage to delete a position then be in a position that I require something or another to get back the operating system.

Can anyone advise how to delete all partitions on my laptop or what steps I need to take to delete the partitions and have Windows 10 running again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First download the official software to make the bootable USB

https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows10ISO

1-While installing you will see the step "Which tipe of installation do you want". Select the "Custom: Install windows only (advanced)" option.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E73630_01/html/E73673/figures/windows2012_install_type_screen.jpg

2-Then you will see the step of "where do you want to install windows":

https://msegceporticoprodassets.blob.core.windows.net/asset-blobs/4052020_en_1

All your partitions will appear there, just delete and format all of them, everything should merge to an unassigned free space.

3-Then just click on "new" and create a partition with as much space as you want and install windows there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks will give that a go. I'm previous version of Windows I've had problems where a USB was not recognised during install. I assume this type of issue is now resolved? Or do I require a DVD disc to save the ISO?

Comment: Check that you are prioritizing booting from an USB in the BIOS. I have always installed Windows with bootable USB drives the last years in several computers without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough points to comment, I comment as an answer: The steps described are correct. Yet, if you don't care about any previous data, partitions, recovery partitions, I suggest you to delete all partitions, do NOT format or make new partitions, and proceed installing on unassigned free space. The advantage of this is that Windows will automatically make a small boot partition, which is a safer option than having one partition containing everything. Also, if you have an UEFI system, it'll also make a partition for necessary UEFI boot data.

Comment: Not fully sure i understand the benefit you're describing here. I usually have 1 OS drive and 1 Data drive (i.e. C and D drives). If i dont create a partition and install on a unassigned free space, i wont have this drive (data drive in this instance). Are you suggesting to install and then create the partition?

Comment: I assumed for years that this hidden partition at the start of the disk was used as a separate boot partition for isolation, as in Unices, separate /boot part. Easier recovery in case something fails, for example a virus (at least not a very sophisticated one) could not touch that boot part. It's the default setup for Windows from Vista or 7 and afterwards. That would be the benefit. But I searched a bit now and cannot find any microsoft doc on this. The wikipedia article refers that it's used only for bitlocker (disk encryption). If that's the case, if you don't encrypt, no benefit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_partition_and_boot_partition#Microsoft_definition

Comment: On the other hand, this article refers that «Windows® usually creates a hidden partition (around 70–200 MB) that stores the Recovery Environment WinRE that is of vital importance, because it allows recovery of the system if any problem is encountered at the time of startup». That's my belief also. I'll probably fire up a Win VM to find out exactly what's in that hidden part.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/hidden-partition

Comment: If you decide to install Win on the undefined free space to have the hidden partition, you can afterwards start the logical volume manager, shrink the C partition and make a D part on the newly available space. All this can be done with your system up, no restart, interruption or booting from something like GParted live needed.